# CSS - borders how to avoid collision

Tags: html, css, border, collision

I created a CSS external file and I'm running into a lot of issues with borders.

I want to create a border for each section, and I want these sections to be separated by a space, and not have their borders collide.

I am running this code: [image with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dONO1.jpg)

And nevertheless, the borders of both sections are colliding.

I'm a noobie, started html + css yesterday.

Comment: Please share your html and css to us, so we can help you.

Comment: Please share some of your code with the community, so we can see what you are doing and what is not working. Consider a service like https://jsbin.com/?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example of it you can adjust how you want it to be.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</section>
<section class="main">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</section>
<section class="main">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Alco, thanks a lot!! I'd like to know, how do I write, now, in those columns? To give you an idea, I'm trying to create a series of columns with written content within like these: https://worldofwarcraft.com/es-es/game/classes

Answer (score 0):

border-spacing only works for a table.
You must know the box model and how the margins and paddings are arranged :

[image: Box-model]